# Filter toggle grays out workbook and only a manual refresh fixes

Tags: tableau-api

This is only happening with one workbook, all others function fine. I've tried live vs extract, restarting and reconnecting/refreshing my data source. Every time I toggle one of my filters, my visual is grayed out. Each time I toggle a filter, I have to right click the data source and refresh.

[image: Workbook]

Answer (score 2):

See [Automatic Updates](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/v10.4/pro/desktop/en-us/help.html#queries_autoupdates.html%3FTocPath%3DReference%7CManage%2520Queries%7C_____1)

In the menu bar, Worksheet -> Auto Updates, "Auto Update Worksheet" is likely unchecked which would cause the described behavior (or use the pause/play icon in the toolbar).